# Optimisation with matrix-vector constraint

Tags: calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I want to optimise

$Q(A, B, y, z) = (\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{Ay}-\mathbf{Bz})^T\mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1}(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{Ay}-\mathbf{Bz})$

with the constraint

$\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1}\mathbf{B}=\mathbf{0}$.

Essentially I want to find optimums for A, B, y and z, so I thought of using a Lagrange multiplier, e.g.:

$Q(A,B,y,z) - \lambda(\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1}\mathbf{B})$

and then differentiate for each of the variables. But the function returns a scalar and the constraint is a vector, so this doesn't make sense.. I guess I can consider a vector of Lagrange multipliers, but how would they relate to the matrix in the constraint? Inner product? I can't find a good source for this (or not sure what exactly to search for!).

Comment: $\lambda$ needs to be a matrix. That is $\operatorname{trace}(\lambda^T A^T \Sigma^{-1} B)$.

Comment: @user251257 Thanks a lot! You can probably put that as an answer? Also I'd be interested to know what resources / books cover this as I'm struggling to find anything but the typical treatment of Lagrangians... (or even just, why is this true?)

Comment: There is nothing special about matrices per se. Just identity $\mathbb R^{m\times n}$ with $\mathbb R^{mn}$.